# What happened to the guns, holsters, belts, and ammo Roland stole from the cops?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

In *The Dark Tower:  Book II:  Drawing of the Three*, Roland enters our world, buys some ammo, and robs two cops before going back to his own world.  He takes the cops' guns, belts, holsters, and spare magazines.

However, after he returns to his own world, the cops' guns, etc, are never mentioned again.

### What happened to all the stuff that Roland stole?

Comment: Didn't he end up giving them to the other three when he began their training as Gunslingers?

Comment: He wouldn't be able to take this stuff through door, only took it away from them  'cause they were fools.

Comment: @Mithoron - No, half the purpose of that trip was getting antibiotics, so he could take care of his fever.  He got that through the door, he got the weapons through as well.  Pretty sure Broklynite is right, but don't remember Susannah's training scene with that detail.

Comment: @Radhil Hmm, I'm pretty sure he only took antibiotics and ammo - only stuff in his pockets. He had to hold it to get it through.

Comment: @Broklynite - Nope - that was his plan, but it never happened.  At first they train with Roland's revolvers, and then Jake came through the door and they added his Ruger to the mix.  In Roland's world, the only guns they have are Roland's revolvers and Jake's semi auto Ruger.

Comment: @Mithoron - Yes, he put the Cheflet (Keflex) and boxes of .45 ammo in his undies before he jumped in front of the train.  The guns, belts, holsters, etc, were last mentioned some time before that.

Answer (score 4):

## Roland threw them aside before going through the door.

Technically, only one of the .38's is called out as being thrown aside. But I think the implication is that the belts were thrown away when he unbuckled his pants.

---

Roland/Mort only took their belts, holsters, and guns:

> He took another quick glance at the clerk, then unbuckled the gunslingers' gunbelts and stripped them off. The he took off Mort's blue suitcoat and buckled the belts on himself. They were the wrong guns, but it still felt good to be packing iron again.
>   - King, Stephen. *The Drawing of the Three:The Dark Tower*. The Pusher. Ll. Signet Book, 1990. Print.

Then, after taking out the other two cops before going down into the subway, he tossed the guns aside and only held on to the ammo boxes and Keflex (emphasis added):

> **He reached the platform and tossed the .38 aside.** He unbuckled Jack Mort's pants and pushed them casually down, revealing a pair of white underdrawers like a whore's panties.
>   ...
>   The gunslinger stuffed the boxes of bullets into the underdrawers, took out the bottle of Keflex, and did the same with it. Now the underdrawers bulged grotesquely. He stripped off the flaming suit-jacket, but made no effort to take off the flaming shirt.
>   - King, Stephen. *The Drawing of the Three:The Dark Tower*. The Pusher. Ll. Signet Book, 1990. Print.

And the extra ammo and Keflex were the only objects that came through the door with Roland:

> Mort shrieked, and in the last split second before the train ran him down, cutting him in two not above the knees but at the waist, Roland lunged at the door ... and through it.
>   Jack Mort died alone.
>   The boxes of ammunition and the bottle of pills appeared beside Roland's physical body. His hands clenched spasmodically at them, then relaxed.
>   - King, Stephen. *The Drawing of the Three:The Dark Tower*. The Pusher. Ll. Signet Book, 1990. Print.

If nothing else, this could be interpreted as: since Roland was only concentrating on bringing the ammo and Keflex through the door then only the ammo and Keflex came through. Nothing else on Jack Mort came through either (Roland was not described as wearing whore's panties, for example).